# How (Can?) you synchronize Windows Live Calendar with a Windows Mobile Phone

Tags: windows, sync, calendar, windows-mobile

This is driving me mad, there must be a way to sync Live Calendars with Windows Mobile phones but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a roundabout, but [Outlook Connector](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA102225181033.aspx), free from Microsoft, will sync Live Calendar to Outlook which you then can sync to your phone.

Comment: THis only works if you've got a Live Mail account, right?

Comment: I used to use Google Calendar Sync (http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955) to sync my Google calendar to Outlook on my computer. Then I sync'd my Outlook calendar to my Windows Mobile phone using ActiveSync. I think that's basically the same two step process as Clifford describes.